Trigger kotlin flow again on pull-to-refresh
I'm currently facing the following problem and hope someone might be able to help:
I have a flow in my ViewModel that provides me with some data. Now I would like this data to be reloaded on pull-to-refresh from ui, but I'm not sure what's the best method to re-trigger the flow or to reload the data.
Perhaps an example will illustrate what I mean:
I have the following ViewModel:
class MyViewModel(
 getSomeDataUsecase : GetSomeDataUseCase
): ViewModel(){
  val myData:Flow<SomeData> = getSomeDataUsecase() // <-- this returns a flow and emits the data

  fun refreshData(){
    // TODO: retrigger "getSomeDataUsecase" to load new data and provide them at "myData"
  }
}

Now I want to trigger the query getSomeDataUsecase again on pull-to-refresh, this should be done via the method refreshData. From there, however, I don't know how best to proceed.
Has anyone had the same problem? I would be interested to know how you solved it.
Thanks in advance :)

The general idea of flows is that you do not need to update them, that's done automatically. To save resources, the flow emissions are only triggered when there is a collector. Flows exposed in the view model should generally be StateFlows (use stateIn on the flow to convert). Executing getSomeDataUsecase() would create a new flow. That's not how it should be. Are you sure that this really needs to be executed again to get new values, or is it just your UI that isn't properly refreshed when the flow emits new values? What exactly does getSomeDataUsecase() do?

Hi @Leviathan,
getSomeDataUsecase() in the end just call a API to get some date from network.
But I don't get how to merge the refresh trigger with the loading of the data while we need to make sure it's emitted in the original flow?
Could you please give me some example on how you would handle this stuff if the network response ( getSomeDataUsecase()) would contain a flow itself?

In clean architecture this will be decoupled: The event from the UI (request to reload data) is passed down through the layers to the data layer where the actual request is performed. There are no return values on the function calls, it's fire-and-forget. Now, the data source that performs the network request eventually receives a response. That response will not be returned to the caller as a return value from a function, instead the data source exposes a property of type Flow and the response is emitted into that flow. That flow is now passed up through the layers into the UI. ...

... The content of the flow may be transformed in between, and the view model converts it into a StateFlow, but eventually that flow reaches the UI where it is collected. In effect, a refresh event from the UI results in a roundtrip through your app layers, but the way down (just simple function calls without return vaues) is independent from the way up (the flow). Therefore you'll never need to concern yourself with how the return values of some action will be received. Just trigger the action and the flows you consume will automatically update when new data arrives.

This principle is also described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#unidirectional-data-flow

Thanks to all your response, I put my solution in a answer below.

How you are using flows now is not how they should be used. You are using flows as a callback for an individual request. A flow should be a subscription and anytime data changes it is submitted to the flow.
Using your code above this is how it should be
class MyViewModel(
 getSomeDataUsecase : GetSomeDataUseCase
): ViewModel(){
  private val _mutableMyData:MutabelStateFLow<SomeData> = MutableStateFlow<SomeData>(initialData)
  val myData:StateFlow<SomeData> = _mutableMyData.asStateFlow()

  suspend fun refreshData(){
    val newData = getSomeDataUsecase()
    _mutableMyData.emit(newData)
  }
}

Then in your activity somewhere you collect your flow
suspend fun listenForFlowUpdates(){
    viewModel.myData.collect{data ->
        //Called when new data is submitted to the flow
        //Update UI and stop your pull to refresh or whatever else
    }
}

Then all you have to do is call the refreshData() in your viewmodel from anywhere and you should get data

My only counter argument is that this can introduce some side effects into Compose code, like needing to use a LaunchedEffect on any Composable that's wants to collect your myData StateFlow. I'm still looking for a better pattern that allows my UI to just observe a data stream from a StateFlow, and let the ViewModel manage when data from the StateFlow needs to be invalidated / refreshed.

@robotsquidward you dont need to use LaunchedEffect to collect a stateflow just use collectAsState or collectAsStateWithLifecycle

Not to observe, but to trigger the initial data load. With this pattern I need to call refreshData() to initiate the data load from the UI somewhere.

@robotsquidward oh I misunderstood, you could just call refreshData in init of viewmodel so that it gets its initial data automatically

The accepted solution requires providing an initial value. To avoid that I stole the idea of using a Channel to signal the Flow to load from CoroutinesRoom:
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val refreshTrigger = Channel<Unit>(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED)
    val myData: Flow<SomeData> = flow {
        for (trigger in refreshTrigger) {
            emit(getSomeData())
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // Do not run above on main thread
        .shareIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.Lazily,
            replay = 1
        ) // Re-use for all subscribers, across config changes

    init {
        refreshData() // Load initial data
    }

    fun refreshData() {
        refreshTrigger.trySend(Unit)
    }

}


I'm not sure why I couldn't get it before so thanks to all you're responses :D .
This is now my solution to handle a manually triggered refresh:
class MyViewModel(
 getSomeDataUsecase : GetSomeDataUseCase
): ViewModel(){

  private val forceRefreshAction = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(
    extraBufferCapacity = 1,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST,
  )
 
  val myData:Flow<SomeData> = forceRefreshAction
    .onStart {
        emit(false)
    }
    .flatMapLatest { forceRefresh ->
        getSomeDataUsecase() // <-- this returns a flow and emits the data
    }
    .flowOn(dispatcher.io)
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000, replayExpirationMillis = 5000),
        initialValue = SomeData(),
    )

  fun refreshData(){
    forceRefreshAction.tryEmit(true) // <-- Called from UI on pull-to-refresh
  }
}


This is hard to understand how and why it works, and it is prone to errors when refactoring. It also defies the principles of clean architecture. Instead you should either use what I layed out in the comments or use @tyczj's approach where GetSomeDataUseCase just returns the data, not a flow.

I find a way like this, it works well.
 class MyViewModel(
     getSomeDataUsecase : GetSomeDataUseCase
 ): ViewModel(){
  private val _pullToRefresh  = MutabelStateFLow(false)

  val refreshResults: StateFlow<List<RefreshResult>> = _pullToRefresh  
    .debounce(300) // Add a debounce to limit requests
    .flatMapLatest(getSomeDataUsecase ::getData)
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, emptyList())

fun pullToRefresh() {
    _pullToRefresh.update { !_pullToRefresh.value  }
    }
}

in activity or fragment, collect flow like this
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED){
                viewModel.refreshResult.collect{
                    //update ui
                }
            }
        }

hope this can help you. :)
reference link：enter link description here
